# To what extent is Javascript used in robots?

Tags: node.js

I originally discouraged my friend against the use of Javascript in his robot project because I didn't know any use for Javascript outside of web developement but then I saw [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1457186950) book on amazon. Since I wouldn't want to mislead him could someone help me develop a better understanding of how often Javascript is used when making robots with an Arduino?

Comment: JavaScript isn't usually used to program Arduino so this site isn't really a good place to ask. You might get better answers on another Stack Exchange site, such as Robotics or Electronics.

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield can the question be transfered

Comment: The question is currently rather broad so it might just get closed at the other sites (which would mean it just gets sent back here). I would recommend investigating what kind of questions the Robotics site will accept, and posting a new question there accordingly.

Comment: Javascript is used for Firmata, and there is a Firmata implementation for Arduino. Cylon.JS is an entire framework, which has support for Arduinos running Firmata. (http://cylonjs.com/documentation/platforms/arduino/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't be my first choice for programming of robotics, but it's certainly doable.

Thanks to NodeJS, JavaScript (or ECMAScript as it is properly known) has broken free of the browser and is now a general programming language.

Thanks to the BeagleBone Black (and others), which runs most of its systems by default through NodeJS, including its web-based IDE, you can program the whole board with ECMAScript.

So yes, you *can* do robotics with ECMAScript, and there are platforms which *do* allow you to do robotics with ECMAScript.

Would you want to do it in a real industrial environment?

As I said - it wouldn't be my first choice.

Comment: Would you want to use an Arduino in a real industrial environment? :) But otherwise I can say JavaScript is used by robots to ship somewhere around 50% of all consumer goods :)

Comment: The Arduino caveat was added after this answer was written. Check the edit history. Before then it didn't specify any hardware, which is why it got closed - nothing to do with Arduino.

Comment: Dude, I made the edit. You think by posting on an Arduino SO it was about something else? I'm just saying, JavaScript does indeed drive industrial robots in some significant way, for more than an Arduino or BeagleBone ever would.

Comment: "You think by posting on an Arduino SO it was about something else?" It often is, yes. You'd be surprised by the amount of stuff about the Pi we get here - and stuff not even remotely related to Arduino.  Just because the site is Arduino doesn't mean that everyone has the intelligence to only ask about Arduino things here...

Comment: But I still stand by my answer. It *may* be used in the industry, but I certainly wouldn't have it as my first choice of language.  Python is used lots these days too - and that is even lower down on my list of languages...